# javascript: how to check all code of an html page is loaded

Tags: javascript

the program needs invoke a function after all code, including HTML, javascript, CSS, etc., is loaded? Can javascript do it?

Comment: Looks like someone downvoted all the answers...

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well. Probably because window.onload didn't exactly cover what Paul was requesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for JavaScript

```
window.onload = function(){
   //your code
};
```

for JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //your code
});
```

Comment: `window.onload` and `$(document).ready` are not equivalent, the first one does what the OP wants, but the second, will fire early, just after the DOM parsing is done (images and other resources might not be loaded yet), the jQuery equivalent would be `$(window).load(function () {/*...*/});`

Comment: @CMS Which would take a performance hit due to waiting for images to be loaded.

Comment: The jQuery ready function is nice.  I've tried messing with all sorts of alternatives and its the best.  Plus you get to use jQuery - (ok I'm biased, but its a great library!)

Comment: @Greg, of course, but that's the *specific requirement* of the OP, I guess he is doing something that relies on the images being already loaded... only he knows...

Comment: I guess Greg is me... :D ... He never stated that images needed to be loaded, just that all the code should be loaded.

Answer (score 4):

`window.onload` will fire after all images, frames and objects have finished loading on the page.  Your question isn't clear enough on whether or not you want the script to wait for those, but if you don't then you need a "document ready" solution.

Firstly, many (all?) DOM-based Javascript frameworks provide this functionality, cross browser in the form of an event.  [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("DOM is ready");
});
```

If you want to do it without the framework, it gets a little more awkward.  Most browsers (*cough*notIE) provide a `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        alert("DOM is ready");
    }, false);
}
```

For IE's part, the `defer` attribute on a script tag will do the job.  You can use conditional comments to make sure only IE parses the script:

```
<!--[if IE]
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
    alert("DOM is ready");
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the jQuery library, you simply do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // The code you need to have executed after loading the page
});
```

Comment: The [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event fires just after the parsing of the document is finished, that's usually *before* other resources like images and subframes are loaded.

Comment: -1 Why push JQuery on people who didn't mention it? Perhaps JQuery is out of scope for either the project or the person asking the question's level of comfort?

Comment: @CMS, true but the DOM is ready for traversal at that point and new nodes can be added without any adverse effect, in most cases.

Comment: @Chris, yes I know, but the OP *specifically wants* to know when *all* the resources are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Your code here
};
```

What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<body onload="doStuff()">`, or you can use `window.onload` in your script.  Check [this](http://javascript.about.com/library/blonload.htm) out.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery $(document).ready(...) method is triggered when the dom is loaded and can be manipulated and before all scripts, images, etc. are loaded.

The window.onload event will fire when everything that has been requested has completed loading.

Answer (score 0):

`document.readyState` can be used to do that. it's much more efficient and easy to use. Also, it provides more options than other ways like `window.onload` or `DOMContentLoaded` in Javascript.

It provides 3 different possible states:

- loading
- interactive
- complete

You can check whether the dom content has been loaded or is loading with these states.

Even the resources like images and scripts can be checked whether they have been loaded or not.

code example:

```js
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
 if(document.readyState === "loading"){
  console.log("content is loading")
 }
 else if(document.readyState === "interactive"){ 
  conosle.log("dom content loaded but resources like image or script has not been loaded yet.")
 }
 else{
   console.log("loading complete.")
 }
});
```